# Why is my request for an ASP resource not routed as expected by Azure API Management?

Tags: azure-api-management

For my use case, I would like to use Azure APIM as a proxy.

**(Edit: I'm using the "Consumption" tier, and the answer given here works with the standard tiers. I will update this if I find a solution with MS support for the Consumption tier.)**

So that a

```
GET https://my-awesome-api.azure-api.net/default.css
```

fetches and returns what sits there:

```
GET https://my-backend.my-domain.com/default.css
```

It works fine, except for ASP files. If my resource is /default.asp, I get a 404 generated directly by the APIM (not my backend, which is not called at all). The problem is reproduced at every level (I can get /foo/default.css, but 404 on /foo/default.asp).

I've not been able to find in the documentation anything related to special handling of ASP files by default (or any other for that matter). The fact that other types of resources work fine is even more puzzling.

```
GET /default.css -> works
GET /default.asp -> gets the Azure 404
GET /i-dont-exist.css -> gets the backend 404
GET /i-dont-exist.asp -> gets Azure 404
```

Azure's 404:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

content-length: 103
content-type: text/html
date: Fri, 05 Apr 2019 15:35:34 GMT
vary: Origin
x-powered-by: ASP.NET
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your API is misconfigured. Seems you want to pass through all traffic, so you need to create API with Web service URL set to "https://my-backend.my-domain.com" and Path suffix to "/".
Underneath it create an operation for each HTTP method you want to proxy with URL template set to /*.

Comment: That's how APIM handles requests. If it can't match one to a predefined operation 404 is returned without talking to backend. And /* just matches any request at all. Don't forget to create an operation for each HTTP method - GET, PUT, POST e.t.c. Methods must be specified explicitly I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, it works with the "standard" tiers of Azure APIM, but my problem is specifically with the "On-Demand" tier. I will update my question to reflect that, and raise a support ticket, as it really looks like a bug.

Comment: You're saying that /* URI template doesn't work with Consumption tier?

Comment: No it works for everything but .asp files. That's the weird thing about it.

Comment: Could you update your question with how you configured APIM, what works, and what not?